# Alsamixer: Headphone volume controls Speaker volume in Acer NE46RS1 Laptop

Tags: alsa, acer

I have recently bought a cheap laptop which has a single integrated speaker and headphone out. The problem is, speaker is not working while headphone works fine. I used alsamixer to figure out what is wrong. When I increase headphone volume, the speaker sound works. But, on next reboot, Headphone volume control gets muted again. How to correctly assign speaker volume.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I found a workaround. I simply installed Alsamixergui (An interface for Alsa), and the program saved my config (headphone volume) to my next boot.