# Headphone volume controlling internal speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

In PulseAudio Volume Control, is I go to Output Devices when port is set to Speakers, my internal laptop speakers do not work.

If I change to Headphones (unplugged) the internal speakers work.

If I plug in headphones, it correctly shows port as Headphones (plugged in) but Speakers is listed as Speakers (unavailable) and the headphones do work.

So it seems like Speakers does not really control my internal speakers.

Currently I have to manually change to Headphones (unplugged) after each reboot in order to get sound working.

Previously my speakers were working but I think I've broken it somehow.

I had run some of the commands from

[post on getting sound to work for HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472258/hdmi-is-not-displayed-in-the-sound-settings-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

```
pulseaudio -k

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt autoremove
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Also my system installed some updates.

Sorry I'm new to Ubuntu / Linux.

I probably should have left things as they were.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/809422/alsamixer-headphone-volume-controls-speaker-volume-in-acer-ne46rs1-laptop seems report same problem but no reply on / solution on that thread either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to resolve the issue, but I've since restored my system (actually did a new install of Ubuntu 16.10, I had Ubuntu 16.04), so I'm no longer having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I found a workaround. I simply installed Alsamixergui (An interface for Alsa), and the program saved my config (headphone volume) to my next boot. This do not resolve the problem, but at least reduce the pain in every boot.